# Declare array constant in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to refactor a SQL query and current query is

```
WITH first_result AS (
    select table.a,table.b,table.c from table where table.a NOT IN 
    ('x', 'y', 'z',.......1000 more entries)),
second_result AS (....),
SELECT * FROM second_result
```

How do I separate the `['x', 'y', 'z',.......1000 more entries]` into a constant? I want to make the query more readable

Answer (score 1):

> The original question was about fixing below query -

```
with first_result as (
    select table.a,table.b,table.c from table where table.a not in 
    ['x', 'y', 'z']),
second_result as (....),
select * from second_result
```

> With the answer

You should use `WHERE a NOT IN UNNEST(['x', 'y', 'z'])` as in below example (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
with first_result as (
    select table.a,table.b,table.c from table where table.a not in 
    UNNEST(['x', 'y', 'z'])  ),
second_result as (....),
select * from second_result
```

Comment: I am able to run the query but want to separate the array into constant to make the query more readable.

Comment: do you mean `WHERE a NOT IN ('x', 'y', 'z')`?